# Is changing the generated context from EF-database-first approach bad practice?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, ef-database-first

The database-model I use is generated within an .edmx file, using the [entity framework database first approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first). 
Now I want to test the database layer with an InMemory database. But the way I found by using [Effort](https://entityframework-effort.net/) makes me change the context which is generated within the .edmx file.

Changing the generated context contradicts the database-first approach in my opinion.

**Standard generated context is:**

```
    public DbContext()
        : base("name=DbConnectionstring")
    { }
```

Which gets the connectionstring from the App.Config file, I didn't find a way to create an InMemory connectionstring for an App.Config file.

**Required context for Effort is:**

```
    public DbContext(DbConnection connection) 
        : base(connection, false)
    { }
```

All the Entity framework examples I know so far are with the [DbOptions/DbOptionsBuilders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory).
Is it true that these options are better suited for dependency injection?

Maybe testing an application developed by the database-first approach is different, and not common with an InMemory database. So can anyone give some proper advise about this, with sources?

Comment: Have you noticed that the generated cs file has the key word `partial` in it?

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't aware of the posibilities. I'll check it right away, thanks to give me advise in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create another file.cs which adds another constructor to your generated Context, since the generated code uses the `partial class` lagnuage feature.

Just create.

`DbContext.Effort.cs`

```
namespace blah.blah.blah
{
     public partial class MyContext
     {

         public MyContext(DbConnection connection) 
            : base(connection, false)
         { }

     }

}
```